# Adding QQuickWidget in QStackedWidget

Tags: qt, qml, qstackedwidget, qquickwidget

I am trying to add a qquickwidget along with some other qwidgets in qstackedwidget. But when I am trying to set the current widget to the qquickwidget nothing appears on the window. Is there something else that need to be done? I am also setting the **view** property of the qquickwidget to true

```
  QQuickWidget* mRoom = new QQuickWidget;
connect(mRoom, SIGNAL(statusChanged(QQuickWidget::Status)), this, SLOT(StatusChanged(QQuickWidget::Status)));
mRoom->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/Users/visjain/Desktop/main_vishwas.qml"));
mRoom->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);

QStackedWidget* mStack = new QStackedWidget(mparent);   
mStack->addWidget(mRoom);
mStack->setCurrentWidget(mRoom);
    mRoom->show();
```

qml code -

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2


Window {
visible: true
height: 1000
width: 1800
Rectangle{
    height: parent.height
    width: parent.width
    color: "red"
}
}
```

Comment: Since you have used `QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView` have you provided `width` and `height`  to root object in QML ?

Comment: I have also attached the qml code

Comment: Are you sure window works? Since you draw only a rectanble maybe try only using this element if at least this works.

Comment: `QQuickWidget` does not support using windows as a root item. So you must replace it with `Item` or `Rectangle` or any component which instantiates `Item`. `QQuickWidget` is in fact an alternative to using `QQuickView` and `QWidget::createWindowContainer()`. And that `QQuickView` can only load components of type `Item`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign some [QML file to the widget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html)?

```
QQuickWidget *view = new QQuickWidget;
view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("myqmlfile.qml"));
view->show();
```

Some more source code might be helpful.

For some more detailed reference you might see [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-quickwidgets-quickwidget-example.html).

---

For putting a `QWidget` inside a `QStackedWidget` to the front you should use `setCurrentIndex` or `setCurrentWidget`. See [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html).

Comment: Yes, maxik I have done all this, Also I am only setting view->show() when I want it to be the current widget in my qstackedwidget