# Embedding a QQuickWidget in a Layout (or in a QWidget) in Python

Tags: python, qml, pyside2, qquickwidget

I use Python and Pyside2, I try to insert a QQuickWidget inside a Qwidget or inside a Layout but I haven't find a solution.
I try with this code:

```
view = QQuickWidget()
view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile("main.qml"))
```

but QQuickWidget start in another windows.
I try use:

```
Layout.addWidget(view)
```

but it required a QWidget and don't work with QQuickWidget.
I found this similar question (in C) but it don't work in Python:
[Adding QQuickWidget in QStackedWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178712/adding-qquickwidget-in-qstackedwidget)

I have try QQmlApplicationEngine and QQuickView, but problem is the some.

Can you help me ?

Edit:
main.qml file is:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "esri"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(39.2160, 9.1344)
        zoomLevel: 16
    }
}
```

Comment: show your main.qml. I think the cause of the problem is in the .qml

Comment: `import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "esri"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(39.2160, 9.1344)
        zoomLevel: 16
    }
}`

Comment: please edit your question and add it there

Comment: I have add it in main question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the root element is a Window that will create a window, the solution is to use an Item:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtLocation 5.6
import QtPositioning 5.6

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "esri"
    }

    Map {
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(39.2160, 9.1344)
        zoomLevel: 16
    }
}
```

Comment: Great ! Now work.
I feel so stupid.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm really sorry that I can give you only one upvote. I'm new to Qt and this solved my problem after almost two days!